# How to define variables from Database options

Tags: php

I have a table of options in a database and I want to pull these out of the database and have them all be defined using the define("DEF_NAME", "DEF_VALUE"), but since they are pulled out of a database they do not have quotations marks around them.

this is the code I currently use:

```
$strOptionName          = $rowDBOptions["strOptionName"];
$strOptionNameUpper = strtoupper($strOptionName);
$strOptionValue     = $rowDBOptions["strOptionValue"];
$inttblOptionsType      = $rowDBOptions["strOptionType"];

define($strOptionNameUpper, $strOptionValue);
```

The only issue is that I receive notices regarding undefined variables. Does anybody know of another option or method to create definitions from database variables?

Comment: The quotes are not the issue.  What exactly do the notices about undefined variables say and what lines? (need code)

Comment: Could you post the exact error message as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine, my own personal method for extracting config from a database goes something like this:

Config database table has a 'key' ie. `GLOBAL_TAX_RATE` and a value, ie. `0.25`

Query looks like:

```
SELECT conf_key, conf_value FROM config_options
```

PHP (after database connection / query execution) looks like:

```
while ($ROW = mysql_fetch_assoc($QRY)) {

  define($ROW['conf_key'],$ROW['conf_value']);

}
```

And you end up with a nice way to define all of your constants from the database without having to explicitly add a new statement if you want to add a new key/value pair.

And there are of course variations, such as on busy sites, storing these values in the session and looping through that - and every 10 minutes using a timestamp, or on login/logout, or whatever you need - refresh the config session values from the database to pick up any changes, without having to run a config SELECT every time someone opens a page.

Comment: That's effectively what I have, I'm just using Variables instead to keep things a bit neater in case somebody else  comes in after the fact.

The definitions are loaded at each page load, so if something changes it is updated at the next page view.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example should work fine.  Please check which line(s) are reported for the notices; it seems that your script relies on a constant that is not in the database.

Comment: The notices are for ALL of the constants that are from the database.  The databases is storing the name of the constant as well as the value.  It does not know of any constants until it parses the list and then creates the definitions from there.

Comment: So you are trying to access the constants before `define()`ing them?  Make sure that you fetch and define all constants before including code that references them.